# Why tensor shape is difference when i use tf.print?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made simple dataset like below.

```
x_data = [[0, 0],
          [0, 1],
          [1, 0],
          [1, 1]]
y_data = [[0],
          [1],
          [1],
          [0]]
```

And I slice it by using `from_tensor_slices`:
(I don't know exact role of tensor slice function...)

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_data, y_data)).batch(len(x_data))
```

when I print dataset using `print` function, it shows like below:

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 2), (None, 1)), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>
```

and when I print it using `for` loop it show like below:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]], shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32) 
tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]], shape=(4, 1), dtype=int32)
```

Here is question:

In my idea, tensor shape should be `(4,2)` and `(4,1)` because row of matrix is 4.

Why when I use `print`, it shows `(None,2)` and `(None,1)`?

And how to print value of tensor without `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- What is `from_tensor_slices`?

- When you use `from_tensor_slices` it creates a **tensorflow dataset** from your input tensors.

2- What is the benefits of using a tensorflow dataset?

- It makes everything you need to do with a dataset, very easy. i.e. you can easily make them `shuffle`, `batch`,preprocess data by `map` and even easily feed to your model like `model.fit(dataset)` etc.

3- Why `print` function shows `BatchDataset` not the values?

- `dataset` variable is an object from `BatchDataset` class (since you defined it like `dataset=from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(bs)`). It is not a python list, eager tensor, numpy array and ... to see its values by `print` function.

4- What can I do to see the values stored in a tf dataset?

- You can access its values by using `take()` function from this class:

```
one_batch = dataset.take(1) # it takes 1 batch of data from dataset

# each batch is a tuple (like what you passed in from_tensor_slices) 
# you passed x and y. So, it returns a batch of x and y
for x,y in one_batch:      
    print(x.shape)
    print(y.shape)
#(4,2) (batch_size, num_features)
#(4,1) (batch_size, labels_dim)
```

5- What are `(None,2)` and `(None,1)` in `BatchDataset` object variable?

- It is the size of `x=(None,2)` and `y=(None,1)`. First dimension is `None`. `None` in the shapes, means that the first dimension of `x` in this dataset (first dimension is number of samples) can be anything, but the second dimension is 2. And the same rule for `y`.

6- How to print values without `for` loop?

- Actually for performance dealing it acts like [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). You can not print all values in once. You can access its elements one by one (batch by batch).